# CSS Elements (DIV) hiding and floating

Tags: css

How can I hide a table element which is **above** a div element when the div element is hovered (mouse over)

CSS only**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple answer; You can't. There is no parent selector in CSS. You need JavaScript to achieve this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: ... if by "above" you mean "ancestor of"

Comment: You could, however, extend the size of the hovered element and therefore overlap (thus "hide") the element above it.

Comment: How can I go about that adam?

Comment: I currently tried to this 

             div {
   
    width:298px;
    height: 62px;
 position:relative; 
 
 
}

div:hover{
    height:90px;
 }

but this doesn't overlap the element above it just hovers downward increasing the height from 62 to 90.

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle.net demo so we can see what you are actually doing.  Right now, we are all guessing.

Comment: here is the fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BradleyCallender/PTbPw/) i want the red element to hide (or overlap) the two squares above it on hover.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your fiddle to work like you asked: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dKRm/). (Note the class "overlap")

```
<div class="overlap" style="">
test
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlap {
    background-color:red; top:-65px; margin:2px; display:block;
}
.overlap:hover{
    top:-160px;
    padding-top:95px;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, can It be done without a class or id?

Comment: Why would you do something like that without a class?

Comment: learning/teaching purposes

Comment: CSS3: `table + div {background-color:red; top:-65px; margin:2px; display:block;}` `table + div:hover{top:-160px; padding-top:95px;}` `+` basically means `after`, so this should work here too

Comment: can you throw it in fiddle?

Comment: I think this should have been enough information, especially when this is for learning purposes. Fiddling around a little on this shouldn't be so hard.